# Adding Event Listener to dynamically created divs

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events

I am trying to add click event listener to my divs that I am creating in my JS dynamically.

My Javascript snippet of function that is called each time to create the Div:

```
var listDiv = document.createElement("div");
listDiv.className = "list";
listDiv.addEventListener = ('click',gotoOutcomesLO, false);
```

The Function that is called by the click event:

```
function gotoOutcomesLO(e){
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
        var ele = e.target;
        var text = ele.getAttribute("name");
        sessionStorage.test = text;
}
}
```

I don't see any click events added to my HTML and not sure what's wrong. Any pointers would be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: remove `=` in `listDiv.addEventListener = ('click',gotoOutcomesLO, false);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
listDiv.addEventListener = ('click',gotoOutcomesLO, false);
```

to

```
listDiv.addEventListener('click',gotoOutcomesLO, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

addEventListener is a function remove equal:

```
var listDiv = document.createElement("div");
listDiv.className = "list";
listDiv.addEventListener('click', gotoOutcomesLO, false);

function gotoOutcomesLO(e) {
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
        var ele = e.target;
        var text = ele.getAttribute("name");
        sessionStorage.test = text;
    }
}
```

Also I guess you append listDiv to a node...

Answer (score 0):

Here is javascript click event

```
var listDiv = document.createElement("div");
listDiv.className = "list";
listDiv.onclick = function(){
   alert('onclick fired')
}
```

Comment: don't use the onclick attribute :(

Comment: Using a chainsaw to cut meat works. This still doesn't mean we should abandon the knife.