# Cannot drop in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using HTML5 to get the function "DnD".
I have a button where i add divs.
I´d like to be able to drag items into this div.
I can drag into my list of divs, but not to the added.
How can i solve this?

**FIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/oxxqk7tj/

**JS**

```
//FlakNr
var flakNr = 1;

//Create flak
$('#btnAddFlak').on('click', function () {
//Flak HTML setup
var flak = $('<div class="flak nopadding dropZone"><div class="flakSideUp"></div><div class="flakMiddle">' + flakNr + '</div><div class="flakSideDown"></div></div><br>');

//Insert flak to flakDiv
$('#flakDiv').append(flak);

//Increase flakNr
flakNr++;

});



// This variable will hold the dragged item object
var dragSrcEl = null;

$('.dropZone').on('dragstart', '.elementDiv', function (e) {
e.stopPropagation();

// Add the CSS class to the element that is being dragged
// This allows to style that element
$(this).addClass('dragging');

dragSrcEl = this;

// Set data transfer object values
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', $(this).html());

});

//The dragged element can be dropped on any other list item (let's call it the drop zone). Dragenter defines what happens when the dragged element enters the zone where it can be dropped:
$('.dropZone').on('dragenter', '.elementDiv', function (e) {
// Add the CSS class to the drop zone
// That way we can indicate the drop location to the user
$('.elementDiv').removeClass('over');
$(this).addClass('over');
});




//When the element leaves the drop zone, the dragleave event is fired:
$('.dropZone').on('dragleave', '.elementDiv', function (e) {
// Element is not a drop zone anymore – remove the CSS class
$(this).removeClass('over');
});

//The dragover event is triggered while the dragged element is in the drop zone:
$('.dropZone').on('dragover', '.elementDiv', function (e) {
// Prevent the default browser behavior
if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
return false;
});



//When the dragging has stopped, we need to clean up the assigned CSS classes used for styling the element being dragged and the drop zones:
$('.dropZone').on('dragend', '.elementDiv', function (e) {

// Remove over and dragging CSS classes  
$(this).removeClass('dragging');
$('.elementDiv').removeClass('over');

});
//The event that contains most of the HTML5 drag and drop logic is the drop event, which is fired after the user drops the element (releases the mouse button):

$('.dropZone').on('drop', '.elementDiv', function (e) {

// Remove over and dragging CSS classes  
$(this).removeClass('dragging');
$('.elementDiv').removeClass('over');

// Stops the browser from redirecting
if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}

// Do the drop only if the dragged item and the drop zone are not the same elements
if (dragSrcEl != this) {
    // Set the dragged element HTML to the HTML of the item we have dropped on.
    $(dragSrcEl).html($(this).html());
    $(this).html(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text/html'));
}

return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that, when you are adding dynamic DIV's to the DOM, you should add events to the newly added div at the time of creation only. The dragstart event should be added to the newly created div while creation itself.  See this link for more details.

[Adding Event Listener to dynamically created divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23881804/adding-event-listener-to-dynamically-created-divs)

Thanks!

Comment: Please share your updated code, will try from my end and let you know.